# how to change value of one input text field based on a specific value of another input text field

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jsp

My HTML Code

```html
<div class="modal-body">
  <form action="edit.jsp" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Order ID</label>
      <input
        type="text"
        name="Order_ID"
        id="txtID"
        class="form-con"
        readonly="readonly"
      />
      <label>Order Amount</label>
      <input type="text" name="Order_Amount" id="txtAMT" class="form-con" />
      <label>Notes</label>
      <input type="text" name="Notes" id="txtNotes" class="form-con" />
      <label>Approved By</label>
      <input type="text" name="Approved_By" id="txtApp" class="form-con" />
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button class="btn" type="submit">EDIT</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

My database:

```
Field            Type           Collation        Null    Key     Default  Extra   Privileges                       Comment  
---------------  -------------  ---------------  ------  ------  -------  ------  -------------------------------  ---------
Order_ID         int            (NULL)           NO      PRI     (NULL)           select,insert,update,references           
Customer_Name    varchar(100)   utf8_general_ci  YES             (NULL)           select,insert,update,references           
Customer_ID      int            (NULL)           YES             (NULL)           select,insert,update,references           
Order_Amount     int            (NULL)           YES             (NULL)           select,insert,update,references           
Approval_Status  varchar(100)   utf8_general_ci  YES             (NULL)           select,insert,update,references           
Approved_By      varchar(100)   utf8_general_ci  YES             (NULL)           select,insert,update,references           
Notes            varchar(1000)  utf8_general_ci  YES             (NULL)           select,insert,update,references           
Order_Date       datetime       (NULL)           YES             (NULL)           select,insert,update,references
```

My query is that: If I change my order amount which is less that 10000 it will autopopulate Approved By field with "David Lee" name. How to acheive this functionality?

Comment: Could you share with us what you have attempted so far, please?

Comment: Changes need to done in backend code i.e : db ?

Answer (score 0):

By using a onchange calling a javascript function to check

(if you enter 20000 as order amount, nothing will change, but if you change it to say 1234 , which is less than 10000, the system will use David Lee as the approved by)

```js
function autopopulate() {
if (document.getElementById("txtAMT").value * 1 < 10000)
{document.getElementById("txtApp").value="David Lee";
}
}
```

```html
<div class="modal-body">
            <form action="edit.jsp" method="post">
                <div class="form-group">
                <label>Order ID</label>
                <input type="text" name="Order_ID" id="txtID" class="form-con" readonly="readonly"><br>
                <label>Order Amount</label>
                <input type="text" name="Order_Amount" id="txtAMT" class="form-con" onchange="javascript:autopopulate();"><br>
                <label>Notes</label>
                <input type="text" name="Notes" id="txtNotes" class="form-con"><br>
                <label>Approved By</label>
                <input type="text" name="Approved_By" id="txtApp" class="form-con">

                
                </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
            <button class="btn" type="submit">EDIT</button>
        </div>
            </form>
            
        </div>
```